# Como utilizar o método find com sum?

Tags: php, yii

Utilizando Yii2, pretendo obter o resultado da seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT data_pagamento, sum(valor_pago) 
FROM tbl_finlegado_titulo_parcela_baixa 
WHERE MONTH(data_pagamento) = 10 
GROUP BY DAY(data_pagamento)
```

Utilizando o método find, ele não me retorna o field `valor_pago`:

```
    $baixas = self::find()
    ->select('data_pagamento, SUM(valor_pago)')
    ->where(['=', "MONTH(data_pagamento)", date('m')])
    ->groupBy('DAY(data_pagamento)')
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se os valores dos campos são retornados no índice de um array ou objeto, então você provavelmente deverá usar um `alias` para `SUM(valor_pago)`. Assim você conseguirá acessar os valores retornados da consulta corretamente - Falo isso porque uso o Laravel, e ele tem esse problema.

Tente fazer assim:

```
$baixas = self::find()
    ->select('data_pagamento, SUM(valor_pago) AS soma_valor')
    ->where(['=', "MONTH(data_pagamento)", date('m')])
    ->groupBy('DAY(data_pagamento)')
    ->all();
```

Comment: É sério que resolveu? Foi um chute muito bem dado.

Comment: Sério, depois fui ver que ele faz a associação do alias da consulta à propriedade do objeto que estava sendo acessado.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, então era realmente a questão que acontece no `Laravel`. Exatamente a mesma coisa.

Comment: A mesma coisa ocorreu logo depois que eu precisei dar um `SELECT DAY(data_pagamento) AS data_pagamento`. Ele automaticamente já faz as associações dos valores.

Answer (score 2):

Também pode ser obtido por

```
$this->find()->where(...)->sum('column');
```